# What is the diffecence between these two if-else block and conditional operator block?

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements

I think those two blocks have same meaning but the second code doesn't work even though the first works.

The second one looks not that cool, but I think it is easier to understand than the first one.

The first one is a part of very simple React practice code on here(https://en.reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)
, and I made a little modification on it.

```
//1st
  const celsius = scale === 'f' ? tryConvert(temperature, toCelsius) : temperature;
  const fahrenheit = scale === 'c' ? tryConvert(temperature, toFahrenheit) : temperature;

//2nd  
  if(scale === 'f') {
    const celsius = tryConvert(temperature, toCelsius);
    const fahrenheit = temperature
  } else if (scale === 'c') {
    const celsius = temperature;
    const fahrenheit = tryConvert(temperature, toFahrenheit);
  } else {
    const celsius = temperature;
    const fahrenheit = temperature;
  }
```

Running my React code including the second codes, Error message appears on console that "celsius is not defined".

In the second code, I think that 'celsius' must be defined whatever 'scale' is because there is else statement in the last of block.

What is the difference between those two codes?

I'm sorry for my bad english..
Thanks for reading my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code works. the problem is that `const` (and also `let`) are so-called ["block scoped"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const). Thus; if you define them inside a if/for/while they are only defined *inside* of that block.

Comment: It works define those variables as let in the outside of if block and change its value inside of block (but It isn't a cool code I think. ) Thanks!

Comment: well, if it looks cool or not is in the eye of the reader :) but _cool_ isn't important compared to readability. You will want to be able to quickly understand what your code does in a year from now and that other people can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is not here in this code. It might be there you accessing celsius variable/constant.
Declare the variable outside the if-else-if block like this

```
 let celsius = temperature
 let fahrenheit = temperature
 if(scale === 'f') {
    celsius = tryConvert(temperature, toCelsius);
 }
 if (scale === 'c') {
    fahrenheit = tryConvert(temperature, toFahrenheit);
 }
```

In this way, you don't need the 3rd block. If you don't like to use a conditional operator and want to make it better, try this.

```
 let celsius = temperature
 let fahrenheit = temperature
 if(scale === 'f') celsius = tryConvert(temperature, toCelsius);
 if (scale === 'c')  fahrenheit = tryConvert(temperature, toFahrenheit);
```